# vue.js: external npm package functionality not working

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I'm developing using the vue-cli tool, and I'm having trouble getting the [Swiper.js](http://idangero.us/swiper/#.WWEBvtPysWo) npm package to work on my site. **TLDR** ***I've loaded in the imports, js initialization, and css, but the swiper is unable to move to other slides past the first slide and remains static on the page.***

[Here is a demo of what I'm trying to implement](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/01-default.html), and [here is the source code for that demo.](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/01-default.html)

---

I'm importing the js and css files from the package right into the particular view `home.vue` where I'm trying to use it.

```
<script>

    //import js and css files
    import Swiper from 'swiper'
    import 'swiper/dist/css/swiper.min.css'

    export default {}

    //initialize swiper
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container'); 

</script>
```

I've also tried importing these files globally into the `main.js` file, although that seems to give the same results.

---

Here is the HTML from the demo that I've placed within `home.vue`'s template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

This renders to the page in the same way as the demo (with Slide 1 displaying and no others visible), but I am unable to move to different slides.

**As well as the accepted answer, this initialization within the view also works:**

```
<script>

  import Swiper from 'swiper'
  import 'swiper/dist/css/swiper.min.css'

  export default {
    mounted(){
      //initialize swiper when document ready  
      var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
      // Optional parameters
      loop: true
      })        
    }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Your new initialization is better. Primarily because if this component was ever removed from the DOM, after page load, and then re-added to the DOM (for example if this component was a route, or using v-if), Swiper would no longer work because `onload` only fires when the *page* loads. `mounted` is ideal for those situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation says, use jquery.onready or document.onload functions. http://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/#.WWEJplGQyUk

```
window.onload = function () {
    //initialize swiper when document ready  
    var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
       // Optional parameters
       direction: 'vertical',
       loop: true
    });
};
```

Comment: That did it. I was trying to use "The best option" from that section. Why does this one work over the other one?

Comment: @coffeebot It doesn't work because the your `new Swiper()` occurs *before* the component is rendered. FWIW, you should really be be wrapping the Swiper library with a component and handling these kinds of initialization in lifecycle events (like `mounted`).

Comment: ah, okay. So rather than using `window.onload`, I should use the lifecycle hook `mounted`? ie `mounted(){ new Swiper etc }`

Comment: @BertEvans I've added what I believe you're saying at the end of my question, which is working for me - thanks. You mentioned "wrapping the Swiper library with a component" - not sure if I'm doing exactly what you're talking about.